# Making a Canvas Viewport Suitable for Multiplayer Game

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, viewport

I have recently been experimenting with the HTML5 Canvas in an io game I am creating, but have run across the issue of the viewport. While making the viewport is not necessarily hard, I have found that showing the other players of the game in the correct positions is difficult (used ctx.translate()). Is it possible that someone could be so kind as to modify my code, or post an example that would help with this.

*The other players render without the viewport code nicely.*

Thanks!

My Code (Client side):

```js
socket.on('state', (gameState) => {
    for (let player in gameState.players) {
        renderEnemies(gameState.players[player]);
    }
});

function renderEnemies(player) {
const ctx = document.getElementById('gameboard').getContext('2d');
var canvas = document.getElementById('gameboard');

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
    ctx.fillRect(110, 30, 50, 50);
    ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById('player'), player.x, player.y);
}

function press(e){
const ctx = document.getElementById('gameboard').getContext('2d');
var canvas = document.getElementById('gameboard');

var startPoint = document.getElementById("gameboard");
  if (e.keyCode === 38 /* up */ || e.keyCode === 87 /* w */){
    ctx.translate(0, 2);
    socket.emit('movement', playerMovement);
    playerMovement.up = true;
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 39 /* right */ || e.keyCode === 68 /* d */){
    ctx.translate(-2, 0);
    socket.emit('movement', playerMovement);
    playerMovement.right = true;
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 40 /* down */ || e.keyCode === 83 /* s */){
    ctx.translate(0, -2);
    socket.emit('movement', playerMovement);
    playerMovement.down = true;
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 37 /* left */ || e.keyCode === 65 /* a */){
    ctx.translate(2, 0);
    socket.emit('movement', playerMovement);
    playerMovement.left = true;
  }
}

function release(e){
  if (e.keyCode === 38 /* up */ || e.keyCode === 87 /* w */){
    playerMovement.up = false;
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 39 /* right */ || e.keyCode === 68 /* d */){
    playerMovement.right = false;
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 40 /* down */ || e.keyCode === 83 /* s */){
    playerMovement.down = false;
  }
  if (e.keyCode === 37 /* left */ || e.keyCode === 65 /* a */){
    playerMovement.left = false;
  }
}
```

*The server sends the movement to the client as player, which means that there can be much lag, so this is another issue to be addressed*

Comment: in your function renderEnemies you are doing clearRect that will wipe the previous player

Answer (score 0):

Expanding what I mentioned on my comment...

You need the `clearRect` outside the loop or you are erasing what you did before, here is a sample:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('gameboard');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

socket.on('state', (gameState) => {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
    ctx.fillRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
    ctx.fillRect(110, 30, 50, 50);

    for (let player in gameState.players) {
        renderEnemy(gameState.players[player]);
    }
});

function renderEnemy(player) {
    ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById('player'), player.x, player.y);
}

function press(e){
  var startPoint = document.getElementById("gameboard");
  if (e.keyCode === 38 /* up */ || e.keyCode === 87 /* w */){
    ctx.translate(0, 2);
    socket.emit('movement', playerMovement);
    playerMovement.up = true;
  }
  ...
}
```

A few things you should looks at:

- moved the canvas and ctx out of the functions and to the top, those should be global since the canvas and context do not change
- changed the name of your function `renderEnemy` singular since you are passing just one item
- moved your clearRect outside renderEnemy that way we clear once then draw all
- also you need to make sure the image is loaded or nothing will show

Comment: This really didn't seem to address the question. For example, the clearRect() does not, in fact "wipe the player" per-se, since the players are just re-drawn directly after. Without the clearRect() in place, each player would leave a "trail." Could you possibly update your answer to include how to make an effective viewport, or how to reduce lag because of sheer amount of client-server messages. You did give me some good ideas, however unrelated :)

Comment: @Finn_Lancaster ... `since the players are just re-drawn directly after`, sorry not in your code, on every call to your renderEnemies you clear the entire canvas and draw one player, if you want create a working sample and we can troubleshoot

Comment: See the for loop. for each player in the array of players, it is drawing that player at the server-sent coords. This part works. My question was focused on a viewport that would position players relative to their actual coords on the viewports of others, as well as how to increase the server-client speed.

Comment: Sorry but that part does not work ... yes it is drawing that player at the server-sent coords but also clearing the canvas, next player on the loop does the same... so you effectively just see the last player

Comment: That's not how that works. That code was modified from an existing io game, and has no issue whatsoever. Just to confirm, I tested with 10 different tabs: all players correctly rendered.

Comment: Yes that is exactly how a canvas works `clearRect` will clear everything on the html canvas ... your test code must different to what you posted here

Comment: The code is the exact same thing. The loop is clearing the players old positions and redrawing them. The loop fires every 60ms, so if players disappear, it is not visible.